# How to set locale for csv.reader in Python?

Tags: python, csv, locale

In Python, when we use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, it converts unquoted fields into float as specified in the documentation:

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No
> automatic data type conversion is performed unless the
> `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` format option is specified (in which case unquoted
> fields are transformed into floats).

The code I wrote looks like this:

```py
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    header = next(csv_reader)

    # Read line by line
    while line := next(csv_reader):
        # Further processing here
```

The number conversion process works fine when the file has the same locale as my default one, `en_GB`. But if data in the file use comma as the decimal separator (`de_DE` locale), the code will break because it cannot convert that string into a float.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,761843944084108'

So, how can I tell the `csv.reader` which locale to use? I tried using `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` before opening the file but somehow it doesn't recognize it and I still got the same error.

An example CSV with `de_DE` looks like this:

```
"ID";"Measurement";"Note"
"1";0,23;"Example Value"
"2";1,5;"Another Note"
```

This file will cause `ValueError` because `0,23` is not a number in `en_GB` locale.

What is the proper way to set locale for the `csv.reader`?

Comment: `while line := next(csv_reader):` **no**. Don't do that. Use `for line in csv_reader: ...`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When we use `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, the `csv.reader` will try to convert unquoted string to number. It means that `line` is a list containing numbers (from unquoted fields) and strings (from quoted fields).

Comment: `locale` won't affect the behavior of `float`, as far as I know. You need to use `locale.atof` to convert a string to a float according to the locale you set

Comment: Ah, I see, well, you are going to have to not use that option and manually convert the strings using `local.atof`... actually, can we see part of the csv?

Comment: Thanks, if I cannot tell `csv.reader` to use the proper locale, I have to do it myself... :)

Comment: How is your csv delimited? can you give a couple of lines as an example?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question with the example input.

Comment: Ah, ok, so then just use `;` as a delimiter, don't use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, and manually use `locale.atof` on the second element of each row after the header

Comment: Yeah, I'm still hoping to avoid some manual work, but it seems I can't.

Answer (score 1):

A method that can help, is while processing that data, to use the function:

```
import locale

locale.atof(input)
```

If your locale is set to `de` for that file in order to handle the values, you can also find more about that function and more options [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html).